# hacer un algoritmo que reciba un User y devuleva un array de sugerencias de username

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Tengo el siguiente metodo que me valida si un username existe en la base de datos,
ahora quiero que este metodo me retorne una lista con 3 username sugeridos.

```
def suggest_username(user, request):
    # Validate username exist    
    user_date = user.birthday 
    user_date_str =  user_date.strftime('%Y')
    user_obtenido =  request.data['username'] 
    username_suggest = user_obtenido + user_date_str
    username_base = User.objects.filter(username = 'username') 
    if username_suggest == username_base:
        message = 'User already exists.'
        raise serializers.ValidationError(message)

    return username_suggest
```

Comment: que yo le de un user y el me entregue un array de cuatro sugerencias

Comment: estoy haciendo este metodo

Comment: def list_username(user):
    list_username = User.objects.filter(user.birthday)            
    username = random.choices( list_username, k=3 )  
    
                    
    return username

Comment: usa el boton [edit]. pone en tu pregunta el codigo que intentaste y aclara cual es tu duda y porque falla...

Comment: listo ya la edite